# For TeXlive 2023, has the list of distro-specific packages to "block" changed?

Tags: texlive, texlive-2023

I had in the past installed TL 2021 and 2022 and always used [the method outlined specifically for Debian-based distros](https://www.tug.org/texlive/debian.html), which recommends using `equivs` to declare both packages which should not be installed when using "vanilla" TeXlive (as opposed to the distro bundled one).

For older TL versions the URLs to the template for `equivs` were (still alive as of this writing):

- https://www.tug.org/texlive/files/debian-equivs-2022-ex.txt
- https://www.tug.org/texlive/files/debian-equivs-2021-ex.txt

Unfortunately changing `2021` or `2022` to `2023` didn't work and the last state of affairs in the above mentioned article still references TL 2022.

**So my closely related questions are:** has the list of packages to "block out" changed or is the TL 2022 state still good to use? If it changed, how?

Comment: Maybe they just haven't updated it? I found [this file](https://github.com/ascherer/tl-equivs/blob/master/debian-equivs-2023-ex.txt) for TL 2023, used it in the usual vanilla install under Ubuntu, and it worked.